# push notification with angular and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, push-notification

I have create push notification with angular and nodejs ..when I valid article i will send push notification to user will create article ... User1 create article and when admin valid this article user1 receive notification ... this is my code in general for receive notification but where is modification in my code for receive notification only for user1 .

code service angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

        const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/subscription';

        @Injectable()
        export class PushNotificationService {
          constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

          public sendSubscriptionToTheServer(subscription: PushSubscription) {
            return this.http.post(SERVER_URL, subscription);
          }
        }
```

code component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';
    import { PushNotificationService } from '../../services/push-notification.service';

    const VAPID_PUBLIC = "BJPrg7jbhWkWZn5mhg0Wti8031cHjsLGyN1G4pmfeippmEsXHo53wnRiqqjApVkA1KQyIz0IYK4ln0ie7RLrsiI";
    const PRIVATE = "D1njq6Y7ny2QexJ-JZXbUpufCkfIywLSMvO6s-iSNoQ";

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test-component',
      templateUrl: './test-component.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./test-component.component.scss']
    })
    export class TestComponentComponent implements OnInit {

       constructor(public swPush: SwPush, public pushService: PushNotificationService) {

       }

        test(){
             if (this.swPush.isEnabled) {
              this.swPush
                .requestSubscription({
                  serverPublicKey: VAPID_PUBLIC
                })
                .then(subscription => {
                    this.pushService.sendSubscriptionToTheServer(subscription).subscribe();
                })
                .catch(console.error);
            }
       }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

code nodejs:

```
const express = require('express');
const webpush = require('web-push');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const PUBLIC_VAPID = 'BJPrg7jbhWkWZn5mhg0Wti8031cHjsLGyN1G4pmfeippmEsXHo53wnRiqqjApVkA1KQyIz0IYK4ln0ie7RLrsiI';
const PRIVATE_VAPID = 'D1njq6Y7ny2QexJ-JZXbUpufCkfIywLSMvO6s-iSNoQ';

const fakeDatabase = [];

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

webpush.setVapidDetails('mailto:mailto@gmail.com', PUBLIC_VAPID, PRIVATE_VAPID);

app.post('/subscription', (req, res) => {
  const subscription = req.body;
  fakeDatabase.push(subscription);

  const notificationPayload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'New Notification',
      body: 'This is the body of the notification',
      icon: 'assets/icons/icon-512x512.png'
    }
  };

  const promises = [];
  fakeDatabase.forEach(subscription => {
    promises.push(webpush.sendNotification(subscription, JSON.stringify(notificationPayload)));
  });
  fakeDatabase.length =0
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => res.sendStatus(200));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

help me and thank you for advanced